# Specify a RGB color in XAML with Xamarin

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm creating some application styles in my app and want to define some explicit colors to use by key. In WPF XAML, I would create a SolidColorBrush to define the RGB/ARGB values. In Xamarin XAML, do I need to convert this to hex to define the same color in XAML? The snippet below is from WPF XAML.

```
<SolidColorBrush
    x:Key="blueColor">
    <SolidColorBrush.Color>
        <Color
            A="255"
            R="50"
            G="150"
            B="225" />
    </SolidColorBrush.Color>
</SolidColorBrush>
```

Comment: Sometimes you think better after writing :) I just tried this and so far it seems ok. Removed the SolidColorBrush and added the key to the Color element

<Color
    x:Key="blueColor"
    A="255"
    R="50"
    G="150"
    B="225">
   </Color>

Comment: Not working.... :(

Answer (score 15):

`Xamarin.Forms` provides a cross-platform `Color` class.

> Using from Xaml:
>
> **Colors can also be easily referenced in Xaml using the defined color names or the Hex representations shown here**:

```
<Label Text="Sea color" BackgroundColor="Aqua" />
<Label Text="RGB" BackgroundColor="#00FF00" />
<Label Text="Alpha plus RGB" BackgroundColor="#CC00FF00" />
<Label Text="Tiny RGB" BackgroundColor="#0F0" />
<Label Text="Tiny Alpha plus RGB" BackgroundColor="#C0F0" />
```

> The Color class provides a number of methods to build a color instance

- Named Colors - a collection of common named-colors, including Red , Green , and Blue .
- FromHex - string value similar to the syntax used in HTML, eg "00FF00".
- Alpha is can optionally be specified as the first pair of characters ("CC00FF00").
- FromHsla - Hue, saturation and luminosity double values, with optional alpha value (0.0-1.0).
- FromRgb - Red, green, and blue int values (0-255).
- FromRgba - Red, green, blue, and alpha int values (0-255).
- FromUint - set a single double value representing argb .

Ref: [Using Colors in Xamarin.Forms](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/working-with/colors/)

Comment: Yes I read that part too and the RGB definition seems not to be available. So I'll just need to convert to HEX.

Comment: Could you edit your answer to be explicit? The question that the OP asked is 'Specify a RGB color in xaml with Xamarin' (not quite a question but close enough). Is the answer that 'you cannot' and that you have to convert to hex?

Comment: Using hex value gives an error in visual studio 15.7.1

Comment: @pollaris what is the exception/error you are getting?

Comment: it is a syntax error - format not allowed.  BTW, I went back to VS15.6.7 and there is no XAML error.   There are other problems with 15.7.1 so I am not going to use it till they are fixed. (see Xamarin Forms exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation)

Comment: I can go around the Visual Studio error by using Build only https://stackoverflow.com/a/52614369/4815184 . The hex color works.

Answer (score 5):

According to Xamarin's [WorkingWithColors](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/blob/master/WorkingWithColors/WorkingWithColors/ColorsInXaml.xaml) sample, you can do something like this:

```
<Color
  x:Key="BlueColor">
  <x:Arguments>
    <x:Double>.4</x:Double> <!-- R/255 -->
    <x:Double>.62</x:Double> <!-- G/255 -->
    <x:Double>.95</x:Double> <!-- B/255 -->
    <x:Double>.2</x:Double> <!-- A: 0.0-1.0 -->
  </x:Arguments>
</Color>
```

Their example doesn't show the use of the alpha channel, but I just tested it and as of May 30th, 2017, it seems to work just fine.

However, be aware that this doesn't seem to be documented. The Xamarin.Forms ["Colors" guide](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/colors/), which goes with the code above, doesn't mention it either, so this may change without notice.

Answer (score 2):

In direct answer to the question, you *cannot* specify a x:FactoryMethod="FromRgb" in xaml for specifying colours in RGB from resources. In order to work around this you must specify colours using the 'FromHex' approach and converting as appropriate e.g.

```
<Color x:Key="somethingGreenish" x:FactoryMethod="FromHex">
    <x:Arguments>
        <x:String>#97cd75</x:String>
    </x:Arguments>
</Color>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
         <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
         <ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="ListViewDemo.MainPage"
         Title="BoxView using Color in XAML">


         <StackLayout>
         <Label Text="My Box View" FontSize="Large" BackgroundColor="LightBlue" />
    <BoxView HeightRequest="50" WidthRequest="50" HorizontalOptions="Center">
        <BoxView.Color>
            <Color x:FactoryMethod="FromRgb">
                <x:Arguments>
                    <x:Int32>192</x:Int32>
                    <x:Int32>75</x:Int32>
                    <x:Int32>150</x:Int32>
                </x:Arguments>
            </Color>
        </BoxView.Color>
    </BoxView>
</StackLayout>
```