# How to set a hex BackgroundColor and integer FontSize in Visual Studio in Xamarin.Forms in XAML?

Tags: visual-studio, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, compiler-errors

My problem is that I am facing errors in **Visual Studio** about the `BackgroundColor` and `fontSize` property on my buttons.

**Desired XAML without Visual Studio errors:**

```
<Button Text="/" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="3"
    BackgroundColor="#FFA500" TextColor="White"
    FontSize="36" BorderRadius="0" />
```

**The Visual Studio errors:**
[image]

However, the XAML documentation sets a hex color as background color so there shouldn't be an error right?:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/colors#using-from-xaml

Comment: You are right, there shouldn't be an error. What is the build action of your file? https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/74365/content-build-action-is-not-supported Have you tried restarting VS? Or maybe you have some pending updates.

Comment: I restarted my PC and updated Visual Studio to 15.8.6 and could now use build + IntelliSense. The errors where still there, but the app was successfully installed on my device. You can create an answer so I can accept it. It's a better answer then mine.

Comment: The errors came back so I can't use build + IntelliSense anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ### Short version:
>
> I created a new solution and it accepts the `FontSize="36"` and
>   `BackgroundColor="#808080"`. The solution I previously used came from
>   a website.
>
> **A few days later I got another error**
>
> [image]
>
> Installing the IDE compatibility for Visual Studio 2017 version 15.8 solved this: https://releases.xamarin.com/category/visual-studio-tools-for-xamarin/

### Long version:

**My temporary solution**

I just set my error list to build only so I can compile my code anyway.

IntelliSense seems to generate the errors, but the hex colors and font size I declared in my XAML are working.

[image]

**What I did that broke my temporary solution**

I cleaned and build the public class library and the platform libraries. I also deleted the iOS and Windows phone library. These steps resulted in the errors below:

[image]

**What worked for me**

I decided to create a new solution and it accepted the `FontSize="36"` and  `BackgroundColor="#808080"` in my XAML file. The solution I previously used came from a website.

**A few days later I got another error**
[image]

Installing the IDE compatibility for Visual Studio 2017 version 15.8 solved this: https://releases.xamarin.com/category/visual-studio-tools-for-xamarin/

Comment: Did you try cleaning and rebuild the library project alone?

Comment: Cleaning and rebuilding didn't work. I had more errors. I deleted the IOS and Windows Phone projects and some errors went away. I only need Android anyway.