# How to set the color in Xamarin forms with Style property with RGBA

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

How to set the color in Xamarin forms with Style property with RGBA.Trying with the below code, but it is not working.

```
<Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="RGBA(0,0,0,0.5)"></Setter>
```

If i change the value to Hex or Color, it works.

```
<Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="#000000"></Setter>
```

Comment: is it case sensitive? rgba instead of RGBA?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36641142/specify-a-rgb-color-in-xaml-with-xamarin/36641523#36641523

Answer (score 9):

You can use color code as say example #80100000. The first two hex values represents the alpha and the remaining six characters is your hex color code. Below are the different alpha values.

- 100% — FF
- 95% — F2
- 90% — E6
- 85% — D9
- 80% — CC
- 75% — BF
- 70% — B3
- 65% — A6
- 60% — 99
- 55% — 8C
- 50% — 80
- 45% — 73
- 40% — 66
- 35% — 59
- 30% — 4D
- 25% — 40
- 20% — 33
- 15% — 26
- 10% — 1A
- 5% — 0D
- 0% — 00

Answer (score 0):

I don't think `RGBA()` is a valid XAML syntax (correct me if I'm wrong).

An alternative to what you might be looking for is found in [this Xamarin Forums thread](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/17310/color-resource-in-xaml%20(Xamarin%20Forms)). In there, StephaneDelcroix suggests using:

```
<Color x:FactoryMethod="FromHex" x:Key="AlmostSilver">
    <x:Arguments>
        <x:String>#ffcccccc</x:String>
    </x:Arguments>
</Color>
```

You could modify that to suit your needs. I would assume (although I haven't tried) you would use:

```
<Color x:FactoryMethod="FromRgba" x:Key="TransparentBlack">
    <x:Arguments>
        <x:Double>0.0</x:Double>
        <x:Double>0.0</x:Double>
        <x:Double>0.0</x:Double>
        <x:Double>0.5</x:Double>
    </x:Arguments>
</Color>
```