# Set WinForms control BackColor with RGB in a WPF Application using XAML?

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, xaml, backcolor

I've created a WinForms RichTextBox and I was able to change it's BackColor to any of the predefied colours using their names but I'm not able to specify the BackColor with **RGB** like so

```
<WindowsFormsHost>
    <wf:RichTextBox x:Name="body" BackColor="Color (13, 13, 17)">
    </wf:RichTextBox>
</WindowsFormsHost>
```

What's the right way to modify the colour of the WinForms control using RGB in **XAML**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question already exist, [Here is a link to it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36641142/specify-a-rgb-color-in-xaml-with-xamarin) :).

Just a recap :

```
<Label Text="Sea color" BackgroundColor="Aqua" />
<Label Text="RGB" BackgroundColor="#00FF00" />
<Label Text="Alpha plus RGB" BackgroundColor="#CC00FF00" />
<Label Text="Tiny RGB" BackgroundColor="#0F0" />
<Label Text="Tiny Alpha plus RGB" BackgroundColor="#C0F0" />
```

Comment: Actually It doesn't exist anywhere because I asked for WinForms. By the way, Your answer helped me because I didn't know that **Hex** colors would ever work on a WinForms control! +1 I did it like that `BackColor="#0D0D11"`

Comment: I'm glad I could help.